# How to test Facebook Real-time updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In order to publish real-time updates to my app, Facebook needs needs to perform a post request to my server.

Problem is, my server is my home computer and not publicly addressable from the internet.  Bringing a server live to implement this sounds like it could be a pain... can't attach debugger, fiddler etc....

So what's the best way to test the Http Endpoint?  Integration tests that simulate the Facebook server?  Fiddling with firewalls/NAT to try and get Facebook talking to my home computer?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ngrok - https://ngrok.com/ - free (pay-what-you-can) service that does exactly what you need. Localtunnel service is down and the developers also recommend ngrok.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I've used LocalTunnel to do this.  It's a nice wrapper around an SSH tunnel and it effectively assigns you a subdomain at localtunnel.com pointing to a port on your localhost.

So basically, when you run it it will spit back an externally accessible sub domain name like xyz.localtunnel.com who's port 80 will point a port you specify on your local box.

You can find it at: http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

It's really great for testing various pubsubhubbub subscription feeds (like Facebook's).

Answer (score 2):

OK! I think NAT should be the best bet and I don't see a reason for it not to work. You should try it out.

Answer (score 2):

It was actually pretty easy - Logged into my home router, set up port forwarding on port 80 to the local IP of my computer, put an exception in windows firewall for port 80. and then navigate to my public IP address in the browser.

Implement the receiver samples at: https://github.com/facebook/real-time/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 0):

The only answer is to get a webserver that is publicly accessible for real-time updates to be able to call back to.

There's lots of free webhosts that allow server-side scripting. And there's lots of paid for webhosts out there too.  Stackoverflow is really not the place to get leads on where/when/why/howmuch for web hosting.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use ngrok only to simulate facebook realtime update since you must make a call to facebook servers with your ngrok adress to validate it (tell me if you find out how to do this :p ).
I use an [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) server to receive facebook realtime and then post evry json data received from facebook to my ngrok adress. So the process is

1. set up an openshift server to receive facebook notifications
2. Facebook sends notifications to your openshift
3. your openshift sends datas (as received) to your ngrok adress

And if you must receive facebook notifications on a local website (like www.website.dev/fb-notifications/) then create a script in your localhost folder which receives openshift posts (let's call it tunelscript.php). the process will be

1. set up an openshift server to receive facebook notifications
2. Facebook sends notifications to your openshift
3. your openshift sends datas (as received) to your tunel script via your ngrok adress (perso.ngrok.com/tunelscript.php)
4. Relay datas from your tunelscript to your local website (tunelscript.php =>  www.website.dev/fb-notifications/)

That's Tuneling B-)

Comment: Plain ngrok works fine for this. You need to pass your correct http://yoursite.ngrok.com/callback URL in 'callback_url' field when doing the HTTP POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/subscriptions to set it up.